# Compare values in separate objects within a v-for loop

Tags: arrays, vue.js, v-for

I have nested objects that I'm accessing in a v-for loop.

I would like to change the color via `v-bind:style` by comparing the current object's tradePrice value with the tradePrice value in the object before it.

`<td v-bind:style="{ color: summary.tradePrice > 0 ? 'red' : 'blue' }">{{ summary.tradePrice }}</td>`

I need something like `summary.tradePrice[1] > summary.tradePrice[0]`, but obviously this is inside of a v-for, so I'm not able to access positions of the object this way.

**This is what the final result should produce:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `v-for` like below and use the `index`

```
<div v-for="(val,index) in summary.tradePrices" :bind="index"></div>
```

Comment: How do I access the previews object's value to compare?

Comment: `index-1` should give you previous object value.

Comment: or to be more precise `summary.tradePrices[index-1]`.

Comment: I've tried this:
`<tr v-for="(transaction, index) in summary.tradePrices" :bind="index">`

`<span v-bind:style="{ color: transaction.tradePrice > transaction.tradePrice[index-1] ? 'red' : 'blue' }">`

</tr>

however no matter whether the change in value is greater or less than, it always makes it `blue`

Comment: should be `<tr v-for="(transaction, index) in summary.tradePrices" :bind="index"> <span v-bind:style="{ color: transaction.tradePrice > summary.tradePrices[index-1].tradePrice ? 'red' : 'blue' }"> </tr>`

Comment: Looking at your object structure it should be like what @IsaFrimpong suggested

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Cannot read property 'tradePrice' of undefined`

It renders if I just use [index-1], so it's finding that, but if I add on the `tradePrice` it fails. Does it have something to do with the fact that the first value in the array won't have a -1 index, since there is nothing before it?

Comment: ofcourse the first item is not going to have any previous. I thought that was clear.